# WooCommerce - If product category statement on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to do an if statement on single product page to echo a link based on product category product category.

I know i can't use `is_product_category()` outside of category archive pages. So i've tried using `has_term` But it's just not echoing what i want. Here's the code i'm using so far.

```
<?php if( has_term( array( 'mac', 'imac', 'macbook', 'imac-pro' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo '<a href="#">All Mac Accessories</a>';
} ?>
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the `has_term` needs a post id in the third parameter. It doesn't automatically take the third parameter as the current post id. You have to manually pass the the current post id. By default, null is passed in the third parameter according to the documentation.

Check it out here, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/

I have the tested the following code in the content-single-product.php and it works perfectly.

```
<?php 
    $terms = ['sagar', 'tamang'];
    if ( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', get_the_ID() ) ) {
       echo '<h1>Yes</h1>';
    } else {
        echo '<h1>No</h1>';
    }

?>
```

You can modify your code as following.

```
<?php
    if( has_term( array( 'mac', 'imac', 'macbook', 'imac-pro' ), 'product_cat', get_the_ID() ) ) {
        echo '<a href="#">All Mac Accessories</a>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Great, glad to help.